# Nutch doesn't fetch graph.facebook response

Tags: regex, apache, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler, nutch

**I cannot crawl links in Facebook's API response**.Everything works fine when i crawl other Web-pages.
I'm using Nutch 2.2.1, Hbase 0.9 for storing and Solr for indexing.
As seed i'm using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?fields=friends%7Bfeed%7Bpermalink_url%7D%2Cname%7D&access_token=<MY_ACC_TOKEN>
```

**Injecting it's ok**.
At the end of the crawling cycle , i have my seed saved in my db.
But during the fetching, **nutch doesn't see any URL**

```
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
-finishing thread FetcherThread49, activeThreads=0
Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5
0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues
```

I've just tried to edit any file that discards URLs that contain **charatchers as probable queries**, but nothing happened.
I've already **implemented https**, it does not work by default.

How can i solve this?

Comment: What do you mean, it _“doesn't see any URL”_? Where exactly would it be supposed to see those …?

Comment: In my api request i've specified the permalink_url field for any feed node of my friend list.I just tried to curl that api request and i can get the urls that i want to crawl with nutch."Doesn t see "mean that the output says "0 pages fetched and 0 urls"

Comment: You’re aware that each one of those friends would have to login to your app and grant it `user_posts` permission, before you can access their feed, right?

Comment: _“and i can get the urls that i want to crawl with nutch”_ - you mean you want to do actual _scraping_? That is not allowed by Facebook.

Comment: Yes i know , i ve got like 10 friend with this-and others- permissions.The problem is that nutch"doesn t see" links out of html tags.This doesn' t happen only with facebook api, but with other web pages too.For example, if i try to use nutch on some pages of wikipedia, i can get all links in exception of some "references section" links, that are in the body-text out of tags.I don t know the proper meaning about "web scraping" , i need text written by people for a semantic analysis with Stanbol without tracking anybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Automated scraping is not allowed on Facebook.**

2. You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission.

See the full ToS here:

https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: And the reason why Nutch does not crawl any page is in https://graph.facebook.com/robots.txt: `User-agent: *
Disallow: /`